# javascript mousemove hide a div - no activity - and show div again when mouse is moved - activity

Tags: javascript

I have two div's one container and DIV2 in that container, when i don't move the mouse for 3 seconds and i am over the container is want to hide DIV2 and when i move the mouse i want to show DIV2 again.

```
<div id=container>
  <div id="2">stuff to show</div>
</div>
```

this is the JavaScript i am using:

```
var timeout;

var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.onmousemove = function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'none';
    }, 3000);
}

container.onmouseover = function () {
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'flex';
};

container.onmouseout = function () {
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'none';
};
```

everything actually works, however when the mouse if already over the container and i move the mouse, DIV2 does not show again. I need to leave the container area and enter it again. How could i add an additional mousemove to this that shows the container again when i move the mouse and hides it again when mouse is not moved, without leaving the container area.

Answer (score 1):

You only need `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` to do this:

```js
var timeout;

var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.onmouseover = function () {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'none';
    }, 3000);
};

container.onmouseout = function () {
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'flex';
};
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id="2">stuff to show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's missing in this solution?

Comment: i can't understand how this would work, first the mouse does not leave the container and second when i enter the container the div is not visible, default hidden. Next to that it seems to me that it will hide the mouse after 3 seconds when i would enter the container.